# How to "add" space to a partitioned hard drive that has windows and Ubuntu

Tags: 11.04, installation, hard-drive

I am post-installation.  I have Windows 7 and the newest version of Ubuntu.  I am obviously an amateur because I screwed up on the partition for the hard drive during installation.

Now, obviously, my Ubuntu is out of space and Windows 7 has hogged all of my space.  How do I "transfer" (parce?) more space from windows 7 to Ubuntu... if its at all possible without a re-installation.  I have GParted if that helps.  If someone knows the answer, please write a step by step for me and all the other noobs who screw up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gparted can resize partitions. The Problem is it can't resize the running system. So the simplest way is to boot from USB or CD - just use whatever you installed Ubuntu from - and run Gparted from there. Then it should be no problem to shrink the Windows 7 ntfs partition and make Ubuntus ext4 one bigger.